# How can I create aws IAM role and policy with helm chart or from init container

Tags: containers, kubernetes-helm, amazon-iam

I want to create aws iam role and policy and i want to do it with helm chart or with the help of kubernetes init container, how can I achieve this use case....

Comment: Helm can normally only create Kubernetes resources.  Do you have some operator-based setup where you could `kubectl apply` a Kubernetes YAML file and that would result in AWS IAM roles being created?  (Do you even have permission to create roles?)

Comment: Regarding permission we can allow it to use aws resources but i couldn't find out how we can actually achieve this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/aws-controllers-k8s/iam-controller, which is an [AWS Controller for Kubernetes](https://github.com/aws-controllers-k8s), which means that you can target and configure AWS resources from inside of a cluster. You'd have to look if the IAM controller covers your needs. There a many services that they have controllers for at this point.